# How do you pull from an external branch?

Tags: git

So say the branches we have are:

- master
- dev-frank
- dev-sam

Say I'm sam. I want all the files that Frank has worked on.  I want these copied locally, so I can work on these and then commit to dev-sam when I'm done.

How do I do this?

I tried:

- git checkout dev-sam
- git fetch origin
- git pull origin dev-frank

I get an error with a large list of files and this message: "Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files. Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm ' as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit."

All of my branch files are out-of-date and need to be overwritten.  There is nothing of importance that needs to be kept from it, so the errors are not relevant.  I just need dev-frank's branch onto my branch dev-sam.

How do I do this without doing a file by file resolution?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to clean your local working directory. This message "Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files..." means that you are in the middle of a merge procedure, so you need to abort it:

```
git reset --hard origin/dev-sam
```

Then you can pull "dev-sam" branch

```
git pull origin dev-frank
```

UPDATE:

If you want the exact branch of "dev-frank" as yours, you can reset to "dev-frank" then force push:

```
git reset --hard origin/dev-frank
git push origin dev-sam --force
```

Comment: I did those exact commands.  But now I get a new error.  It says Conflict (content): Merge conflict in (filename).  Auto-merging (filename).  That is repeated many times, then it says "Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result."  How do I ignore conflicts and just override what is on my branch?